# Returning an object from ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to do an ajax request to get data and input it into a function `parse()`.  The function works when I don't use ajax, but when I use ajax, it doesn't work.

```
    $.get(url,function(data){ 
        parse(data);
    });
```

The ajax response:

```
  {"all": 
     {label: "All", 
      data:  [
               ["11/30/2012",12],null,null,null,["01/24/2013",1442],["01/25/2013",1561]
             ]
     }
  };
```

---

However, when I call my parse function like this, it works:

```
var data = {"all": 
 {label: "All", 
  data:  [
           ["11/30/2012",12],null,null,null,["01/24/2013",1442],["01/25/2013",1561]
         ]
 }
};

parse(data);
```

I even tried adding `data =` in front of the text in my ajax response, but the function still didn't recognize it.

Anyone know how to return an object from an ajax request?

Comment: Are you sure data is what you think it is? Is it a string and not an object?

Comment: console log `data` and see that you're getting what you think, or anything at all ?

Comment: You code being returned in `data` is not valid JSON so it will not parse properly with `JSON.parse()`. So it will be a string or an error depending on how jQuery handles the get request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function, which will cause the response to be parsed as JSON.

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){ 
        parse(data);
});
```

or use `get()` with the `dataType` argument specified.  The `dataType` indicates the type of data expected to be returned by the server.

```
$.get(url,function(data){ 
    parse(data);
}, "json");
```

Also consider reformatting the JSON so that it is valid (uses quotes around property names):

```
{
    "all": {
        "label": "All",
        "data": [
            [
                "11/30/2012",
                12
            ],
            null,
            null,
            null,
            [
                "01/24/2013",
                1442
            ],
            [
                "01/25/2013",
                1561
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this would be different than using normal `get()` like I'm doing?

Comment: @ZeeTee It will cause the response to be parsed as JSON.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't even load. I put `alert(1)` in the callback (above `parse(data)`) and it doesn't even trigger. And i tried it with quotes and without.

Comment: Are you familiar with firebug?

Comment: Yea i'm using it, the ajax request goes through, it just doesnt trigger on the callback.

Comment: Does anything come back in the response?  Is there a json tab with the response?

Comment: Yea, the data I posted in my question (with and w/out quotes)

Comment: The data you posted in your question is not proper json syntax.  Have you modified the syntax?

Comment: But I want to return the object, not JSON

Comment: All that can go over the wire is a string, you can't pass a javascript object. Normally you pass the object as a json string and then parse it to an object.

Comment: The way you wrote your `fix` code, doesn't work then. If you know this, why didn't you mention it before?

Comment: I assumed the json was valid at the time, I was wrong.  Are you able to modify the String passed over the wire?

Comment: I want to avoid doing that if I can.